# Selecting a with containing div to make background image appear

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, addclass

A web page I'm working uses a basic CSS effect that shows an image when user hovers the mouse over the link.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a href="" id="first-link"><div id="first-image"></div>First link text</a>
            <a href="" id="second-link"><div id="second-image"></div>Second link text</a>
            <a href="" id="third-link"><div id="third image"></div>Third link text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- #container -->
```

Each `div` inside the `a` has a background image applied to it in CSS. Here's the CSS that makes images appear when a link is hovered over:

```
#first-link:hover #first-image,
#second-link:hover #second-image,
#third-link:hover #third-image {
    display:block;
}
```

Now I want to add jQuery: I want the script to select a random `a` and the `div` it contains (as if "forcing" the mouse hover).

To be able to do this, I am adding .jquery-select class to HTML, which would allow me to select the `a`'s that I want:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a href="" id="first-link" class="jquery-select"><div id="first-image"></div>First link text</a>
            <a href="" id="second-link" class="jquery-select"><div id="second-image"></div>Second link text</a>
            <a href="" id="third-link" class="jquery-select"><div id="third image"></div>Third link text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- #container -->
```

And I'm also adding the .hovered class to CSS:

```
#first-link:hover #first-image,
#second-link:hover #second-image,
#third-link:hover #third-image,

#first-link.hovered #first-image,
#second-link.hovered #second-image,
#third-link.hovered #third-image {
    display:block;
}
```

Then I'm picking a random number with JavaScript:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
```

And I want to add .hovered class to a randomly chosen `a` which contains a `div`:

```
$("a.jquery-select").eq(random).children("div").addClass("hovered");
```

And this is where my efforts fail miserably, because somehow nothing gets selected, and the random image doesn't display. Either my selection is wrong, or I'm assigning the .hovered class to a wrong element in CSS or with jQuery, or all of the above – and I can't figure out how to make it work.

So, I need advice from someone who knows these things a little better. How do I make it work?

Comment: what happens when you log `random` in the console? Is there a corresponding element at that index returned by `$("a.jquery-select")`?

Comment: Also, it seems like you should be adding the `hovered` class to the anchor tag itself and not the child div.

Comment: As a side note, you could get rid of those divs and just make your `a` elements block or inline-block and give them the background images.

Comment: can you show whats happening on jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you explain to me, please, how to add that class to the anchor tag, while still targeting the div, @crowjohan? (When I add the class only to the anchor tag, it gets randomly selected, but the image doesn't pop up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("a.jquery-select").eq(random).children("div").show();`

```
#firstlink:hover #first, #secondlink:hover #second, #thirdlink:hover #third {
    display:block !important;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}

function temp(){
    $("a.jquery-select").eq($(window).data("rand")).children("div").hide();

}
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
$(window).data("rand",random);
$("a.jquery-select").eq(random).children("div").show();
$("a.jquery-select").mouseenter(temp);
```

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MYRJq/2/)**

**[DEMO JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/amejaq/1/)**

**As per comment below you will need code similar to this...**

HTML

```
<div id="image" style="width:100px;height: 100px"></div>
<div id="container">
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="first-link" class="jquery-select">First link text</a>
            <a href="#" id="second-link" class="jquery-select">Second link text</a>
            <a href="#" id="third-link" class="jquery-select">Third link text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQUery Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var images=["http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif","http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif","http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif"];

      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

   $("a.jquery-select").mouseenter(function () {
    var div=$("#image");
    $("a.jquery-select").css("border","none");
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
    div.css("background","url("+images[$(this).index()]+")");
    div.show();
  }).mouseleave( function () {
         $(this).css("border", "none")
    });
  $("#image").css("background-image","url("+images[random]+")");
   $("a.jquery-select").eq(random).css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
});
```

**[NEW DEMO JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/amejaq/3)**

**[NEW DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9NLkC/5/)**

to  links get randomly selected at a certain interval use

```
setInterval(function(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      $("#image").css("background-image","url("+images[random]+")");
      $("a.jquery-select").css("border","none");
      $("a.jquery-select").eq(random).css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
},1000);
```

instead of last two lines in above code...

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction, @rahul, but still doesn't work: the anchor doesn't get selected. What I need is something like this: $("a.jquery-select").eq(random).addClass("hovered").children("div"); – to add the class to the anchor tag and then target the child div – but I can't figure out the syntax. Would appreciate your insight.

Comment: See updated answer I think you are looking for this functioanlity.. if not please elaborate 'then target the child div'

Comment: May I ask you to take a look at the actual web page, please, @rahul? Thank you for helping me with this – unfortunately, JSFiddle option is not available to me, because my IT people at work block a lot of websites, and somehow JSFiddle got blocked, too.

Comment: give me your URL...I am at work too... and facing similar issues ;) with links

Comment: @Piano whats not working there..? i do see 1 image on startup.. and when i hover other products those come up too... what is worng there?? I am checking on Chrome.

Comment: LOL, well, @rahul, if you refresh the page a few times, you will see that links get selected at random, but the initial image stays the same. ;-) Beating my head against the wall right now.

Comment: My mistake when asking the initial question was how the images appear on hover. On hover, the background is added in CSS rule, rather than display:block. Honest mistake, not intentional, @rahul.

Comment: can you see jsbin example? if yes then i will try to update it

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at it, and it works well, @rahul. Were you able to see my actual CSS from the site? Sorry for all the inconvenience I caused by simplifying it in the body of the question...

Comment: is complete jquery solution ok for you? or you want it to be mergerd with css hover?

Comment: Actually, I set up the CSS hover behavior only for those guys who don't have JavaScript enabled, @rahul. Ideally, what I would want as the final result is to make it look like the links get randomly selected at a certain interval, and the corresponding image fades in - plus, if a user selects a link by hovering over it, the same happens for the link that the user selected. Trying to figure out how to achieve that, but failed at the first step. ;-( Would be super-grateful if you could help.

Comment: @Piano check updated answer...I am leaving from owrk to home now.. almost one hour i cant reply... if this helped you dont forget to accept as answer:) and or upvote

Comment: I definitely will accept the answer simply because you've been so helpful, @rahul. I think I need a little higher reputation to be able to upvote, though. I suspect may have to ask you a couple more questions though when you're available.

Comment: may be after a hour.. bye for now

Comment: @Piano Check updated code and let me know... I think it should work in your case...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkUd/) with some working code. You will notice to that before the .hovered class is applied to a random div, it is first removed from whichever div currently has it. Otherwise all divs will end up with the hovered class.

You are confusing the pseudo class `:hover` with the class `hovered`. Your css uses the pseudo class but your jQuery is adding an actual class.

Comment: I'm aware of that, @ogc-nick, but that's why I added the class `hovered` to the CSS. So I'm targeting with jQuery something that does exist in CSS, only I'm not doing it correctly, somehow. Would appreciate more insight from you.

Comment: It will work, if you have the correct CSS on your anchors/divs, [check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYRJq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the "hovered" class to the div instead of the anchor. Use the following instead.

```
$("a.jquery-select").eq(random).addClass("hovered");
```

Comment: This selects the anchor tags correcty, but the image doesn't display. How can I add the included div into it, @user1855126?